# Gulp build task CSS paths and JS compilation

Tags: javascript, gulp, pug

So I have the following basic project structure that I use throughout all my projects:
[image]

Where the *src* folder looks like this:

[image]

I use Pug(Jade), sass compiling and useref js compilation.

This is my Jade views structure:

[image]

And this is my Jade index file:

[image]

This is my Jade scripts file, that is included in the index:

[image]

This is my pre-build index file, which is constructed by the index.pug:

[image]

And this is the build version of the index file:

[image]

My Gulpfile looks like this:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
 sass = require('gulp-sass'),
 plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
 changed = require('gulp-changed'),
 gutil = require('gulp-util'),
 pug = require('gulp-pug'),
 concat = require('gulp-concat'),
 browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
 useref = require('gulp-useref'),
 uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
 gulpIf = require('gulp-if'),
 cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano'),
 imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
 cache = require('gulp-cache'),
 del = require('del'),
 cssAdjustUrlPath = require('gulp-css-adjust-url-path'),
 runSequence = require('run-sequence');

function handleError(err) {
 gutil.beep();
 console.log(err.toString());
 this.emit('end');
}

gulp.task('sass', function () {
 return gulp.src('src/scss/**/*.scss')
  .pipe(plumber({
   errorHandler: handleError
  }))
  .pipe(sass()) // Using gulp-sass
  .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css'))
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({
   stream: true
  }));
});

gulp.task('sass-dist', function () {
 return gulp.src('src/scss/**/*.scss')
  .pipe(cssAdjustUrlPath(/(url\(['"]?)[/]?(assets)/g))
  .pipe(sass()) // Using gulp-sass
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
});

gulp.task('views', function buildHTML() {
 return gulp.src('src/views/*.pug')
  .pipe(changed('src', {
   extension: '.html'
  }))
  .pipe(pug({
   pretty: true
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('src/'))
});

gulp.task('views-dist', function buildHTML() {
 return gulp.src('src/views/*.pug')
  .pipe(changed('src', {
   extension: '.html'
  }))
  .pipe(pug({
   pretty: true
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'views', 'sass'], function () {
 gulp.watch('src/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
 gulp.watch('src/views/**/*.pug', ['views']);
 // Reloads the browser whenever HTML or JS files change
 gulp.watch('src/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
 gulp.watch('src/*.html', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function () {
 browserSync.init({
  server: {
   baseDir: 'src'
  },
  port: 3000
 });
});

gulp.task('useref', function () {
 return gulp.src('src/*.html')
  .pipe(useref())
  .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
  // Minifies only if it's a CSS file
  .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('useref-dist', function () {
 return gulp.src('src/**/*.html')
  .pipe(useref())
  .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
  // Minifies only if it's a CSS file
  .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});


gulp.task('images', function () {
 return gulp.src('src/images/**/*.+(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)')
  // Caching images that ran through imagemin
  .pipe(cache(imagemin({
   interlaced: true
  })))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('src/images/'));
});

gulp.task('images-dist', function () {
 return gulp.src('src/images/**/*.+(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)')
  // Caching images that ran through imagemin
  .pipe(cache(imagemin({
   interlaced: true
  })))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images/'));
});

gulp.task('fonts', function () {
 return gulp.src('src/fonts/**/*')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'));
});

gulp.task('clean:dist', function () {
 return del.sync('dist');
});

gulp.task('build', function (callback) {
 runSequence('clean:dist', ['sass-dist', 'useref-dist', 'images-dist', 'fonts', 'views-dist'],
  callback
 );
});

gulp.task('default', function (callback) {
 runSequence(['views', 'sass', 'browserSync', 'watch'],
  callback
 );
});
```

When I run the build task `gulp build`, all is well, except the relative/absolute paths *inside* the outputted CSS files, and the JS that runs the final product, whereas fonts/backgrounds/icons and JS functionality is not translated into the final build.

What is wrong with my Gulp file, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried `gulp.dest('./output/path')` (adding `./` to the front of the path)?

Comment: I meant the absolute/relative paths *within* the files. Inside the output CSS, and the proper JS output.

Comment: @snkv off-topic, but which editor are you using? I really like the contrast in the colors

Comment: @Tyler , VS Code with the JetJet-alternate theme, but with some small custom adjustments.

Comment: Just snagged that theme. I like it. :)